# How to call webmethod with a list as parameter from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have created a webmethod from code behind that returns as value a list. I have also create a function in javascript that invokes webmethod with its parameter. But I want to pass the list that is being returned from webmethod in javascript. Below you can see the code.
Thank you in advance!

```
'vb.net 
<WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function listTest(ByVal Example As String) As ArrayList
Dim myList As New ArrayList
       'Some Code
Return myList
End Function


'javascript function 

function test() {
PageMethods.listTest(Example);

                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `callback` function for that, I don't know which type of list you are returning from your `webmethod`, but in success `callback` function you can handle it, like below:

```
function onSuccess(result) {
    //Handle result here as list
    alert(result);
}

function onFailure(error) {
    alert("Failed to get values from server!");
}
```

and call your `webmethod` like :

```
PageMethods.listTest(Example, onSuccess, onFailure);
```

if your method returns a list properly then you can do iteration on returned list something like:

```
function onSuccess(result) {
   //Handle result here as list
   for(var i=0;i<=result.length-1;i++)
    {
       //here you can get the item of list one by one 
       //result[i]
    }
}
```